# Titanium Studio - Not able to run 'Hello World' program

Tags: android, titanium

Not able to run my first application... Disappointing!

I have installed Titanium studio + Android SDK / NDK.

I tried to use Android Emulator or a real Android device and in both cases I have the same behaviour : I click on Run and nothing happens.

So my question is: How can I debug this to find where is the problem?

I show the log file but it keeps empty when I run something...

Please help :(

Comment: Is your'r device/emulator able to connect via adb. Try "adb devices" and update what do you see. It appears that you are able to see logs from device/emulator, can you please post logs from command "adb logcat"

Comment: I plugged my phone, and "adb devices" returns "06a2067b5117049f        device", so it find it.
If I do "adb logcat", it displays lot of logs and it never ends. I think this is the log of the running applications I have on my phone.

Comment: I understand it might be a little tricky to capture the right log segment that is coming from application. But I'm afraid that this information is not enough to provide some suggestions. You may check one thing that your application has a launcher activity (which helps it being launched from the launcher application) or you can launch any specific activity from eclipse. OR you could use this adb shell to try launching an app activity. am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname

Comment: I tried Android Studio and everything works like a charm (mobile + emulator)
I tried Qt Mobility and it works on my mobile. On the emulator, I have problem with openGL ES and a blank page appears.
I don't know if it helps to find where is the problem with Titanium.
I think Titanium does not manage to compile or to deploy the project and I don't see any errors in the terminal, and nothing in the console too. Where is the error log?